# How to make a search api using mongoDb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, routes

i am trying to make a search api using mongodb .This is what i did;

```
export const searchRomance=async (req,res) => {
    const nameis=req.params.key
    const searchR = await romances.find({
        name:nameis
    })
    
    if(!searchR ) res.status(400).send({error : "No task was found"})
    res.status(200).send(searchR)
}
```

and this is how i made the route  ==>router.get('/search/:key',searchRomance);

when i do this instead of getting only the search result am getting everything!. please  answer.